# Responsive vs adaptive vs fixed size video player

Tags: usability, web-app, responsive-design

I am thinking to create browser plugin/extension to play videos over the webpage but from user experience point of view I am having doubt regarding size of player.

Shall I keep it:

- Responsive : so that user can resize as he desires by giving resize option at corners
- or Adaptive by giving 2 or 3 fixed aspect ratios like youtube provides
- or Single fixed video size

Answer (score 1):

There's a comprehensive topic on this here:

[Fluid Video](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

With regards to the right and wrongs of UX/UI, my opinion would be the needs of the video to be shown to the user and how visible it would be in an extremely small view port.

Comment: visibility on smaller view port yeah it makes point